Why does commented out parentheses match non commented parentheses?
If I have
(foo
;)
)

, then the last parentheses shows up as
No matching parentheses found

What gives?;)

Presumably because whatever mechanism you are using for matching parentheses is implemented using regexps (or some such ad-hoc mechanism that is unaware of the context) and does not parse the text to figure out what is a comment and what is not. What mechanism are you using?

Specify what you're doing to see the error msg.
